# ExpressJS API routes when hosting app in subdirectory

Tags: node.js, express

I have one app hosted at the root and I would like to host this new app in a subdirectory /rps using proxypass etc. Everything is working fine except when I try to call my api I get 404 errors in routes for example https://myapp.com/rps/api/posts/. The front end app is basically static served from the public folder of express.

Open to any ideas what I may doing wrong or alternate methods. I'd really like not to have a new server for this small application and I can't really build it into the already existing app. Of course, the routes were working locally, just not when I host in my strange scenario on the server...

See code:

(server) index.js:

```
const config = require('./config.js');    

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;   

var indexRouter = express.Router();    

const posts = require('./routes/api/posts')

indexRouter.use('/api/posts', posts)    

app.use(express.static(__dirname+ '/public'))

indexRouter.get(/.*/, (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html'))

app.use(config.baseUrl, indexRouter);
```

(server) config.js:

```
module.exports  = {
    baseUrl: '/rps/',
}
```

(server) ./routes/api/posts.js:

```
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    //gets my thang in action...
})

module.exports = router
```

(client) main.js:

```
axios.post('/api/posts/', { //  /rps/api/posts ??
    stuff: things,    
})
.then(function (response) {
    // do something else
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: My first guess is that `config.baseUrl` should be `/rps`, not `/rps/`.  You don't want `app.use('/rps/', indexRouter)`.  Instead, you want `app.use('/rps', indexRouter)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I tried that, its still giving 404 error at that route.